# Ask for authorization to Photo Roll without writing to it

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

I am using `ALAssetLibrary` and would like iOS to automatically show the permission dialog to the user when the authorization status is not determined without adding anything new to the Photo Roll itself.

Currently I am using on the `AppDelegate` :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // checks for permission, iOS automatically prompt the first boot if not
    ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];

    if (status == ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [AssetsLibraryWrapper sharedInstance] createGroupAlbum];
    }    

    return YES;
}
```

This unfortunately creates a new Album in the library that I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a group, use `ALAssetsLibrary` and simply try to enumerate the groups.

```
if (status == ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [lib enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        // Access granted
        *stop = YES; // no need to complete iteration
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        // Access denied
    }
}
```